# How do I set up a method that sets the text of multiple JLabels?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jlabel

```
cannonCounter1.setText(cannonAccu1 + "/" + cannonMax);
cannonCounter2.setText(cannonAccu2 + "/" + cannonMax);
cannonCounter3.setText(cannonAccu3 + "/" + cannonMax);
cannonCounter4.setText(cannonAccu4 + "/" + cannonMax);
cannonCounter5.setText(cannonAccu5 + "/" + cannonMax);
cannonCounter6.setText(cannonAccu6 + "/" + cannonMax);
```

I'm trying to set up a method that shortens these lines of code. The only difference between each line is the counter variable name changes, and the accumulator variable name changes. I would just leave it because it works but as my program expands there will be around 500-1000 of these lines that are almost exactly the same. I am trying to create a method but have no idea how to get the method to set the text for multiple `JLabels`!! Any ideas, or will I just have to leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of `JLabels` and loop over it.

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[6];
for (int i = 0 ; i < labels.length ; i++)
    labels[i].setText(yourtext);
```

Of course, each index should contain a `JLabel` before the loop. This is just an example.

Comment: Thank You! I have since figured out a way to do it. I just added all of the JLabels to a JLabel specific ArrayList. Then I passed that ArrayList to a method that runs through each index and sets it to the correct text!

Comment: @NicholasLong that's also a way to do it indeed :) Do not hesitate to mark the answer as accepted.